# Google Play Services GCM

Tags: android

I try to add google analitics to my app but I get error in build.gradle:

```
  Error:  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProductionDebugResources'.
    \app\build\generated\res\google-services\production\debug\xml\global_tracker.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

but the wrong in my code:
This is my app level gradle 
    android {

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('src/main/java/libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/libs/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.5.1.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/libs/quickblox-android-sdk-content-2.5.1.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/libs/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.5.1.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/libs/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.5.1.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/libs/bugsense-3.5.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'

    compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'

    compile "com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

and this is my project level gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'  
}
}
```

**Edit:**
**when I remove global_tracker.xml
the runOnUiThread in:**

```
import static com.google.android.gms.internal.zzir.runOnUiThread;
```

**not know!!!**

Comment: You shouldn't be adding both the full play-services module and the specific ones. Just keep play-services-auth and play-services-analytics if you need just those 2 and lose the `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'`

Comment: May be by removing this line: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the global_tracker.xml from your xml folder, as the google-services plugin will automatically add all the required data from the google-services.json configuration file when building your app.

Comment: whice global_tracker.xml remove?  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProductionDebugResources'.
> [xml/global_tracker] C:\gitHubNewServerMap\app\src\main\res\xml\global_tracker.xml [xml/global_tracker] C:\gitHubNewServerMap\app\build\generated\res\google-services\production\debug\xml\global_tracker.xml: Error: Duplicate resources